# Representing a graph with an adjacency matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, dijkstra

```
# Creating the graph as an adjacency matrix
vertices = [[0, 1, 1, 0],
            [0, 0, 1, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 1],
            [0, 0, 0, 0]]
edges =  [[0, 3, 4, 0],
          [0, 0, 0.5, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 1],
          [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

So I am trying to understand Dijkstra's algorithm in python but I don't understand the graph clearly since I don't understand the real meaning of each sublist, I understand that certain numbers like 3, 4, 1 and 0.5 are the distances of certain vericles but thats really it. I am attaching the image of what the graph looks like visually.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adjacency matrices show information between pairs of vertices. In this example, you should interpret the lists like a matrix where the elements in each row and column corresponds to a pair of vertices:

```
  a b c d
a 0 1 1 0
b 0 0 1 0
c 0 0 0 1
d 0 0 0 0
```

Here, a 0 in the `a` column and `a` row, or at the position (0, 0) signifies that there is no edge from the `a` node to the `a` node and a 1 in the `b` column and the `a` row or position (0, 1) signifies that there is an edge from the `a` node to the `b` node. In other words, anywhere there is a 1, it signifies that there is an edge starting at the node corresponding to the row and ending at the node corresponding to the column, whereas a 0 signifies that there isn't an edge.

Apply similar logic to the `edges` list, which instead marks the weight of the edge rather than just marking whether an edge exists or not. As @misha mentioned, this list is not enough to represent the interconnectedness of nodes, because edges between nodes may have a weight of 0, which would be indistinguishable from an edge not existing at all, so both the `edges` and the `vertices` matrices are necessary

Comment: It is important to note that the `weight` of an edge can also be 0, hence the `edges` matrix is not enough to represent a graph, and the `vertices` matrix is essential.

Comment: thanks for this comment! I understand it now thank you!

Comment: also, I have a question as to how I would implement this algorithm in a grid made in pygame where I ask the user to choose a start point and an endpoint? Like I think the weight would just be 1 for every block (until I perhaps add obstacles of some sort which are higher weights) but how would I actually create like the graph for instance?

Comment: @jackbob no problem. I've done something similar before, and I approached it by creating a `Grid` class which was a wrapper around a 2D list representing the x,y coordinates of the grid system. As you guessed, the weight would just be 1, and then there is no need for a adjacency matrices because you know that the four (unless it's at the border) grid blocks adjacent to a single grid block are the adjacent nodes. Or, if you're including diagonal movement, then the 8 adjacent grid blocks. Does this help?

Comment: This is what I understood from what you said, basically create a Grid class which has certain properties such as having a weight of 1 like I said and also figuring out if the cell we are analyzing or checking is a border which means it has 3 other neighbouring cells if its on the border then it has 5 neighbouring cells and otherwise it will have 8 neighbouring cells. I don't understand what exactly you meant with the wrapper part. Also to use apply this algorithm I basically have to check cell by cell and then its neighbours and update the weight right?

Comment: By the wrapper part, I just meant that the `Grid` class will internally hold a 2D list and then you can expose methods on the class to interact with the list (get, set, etc.). Yeah, just define a `get_neighbors` function on your `Grid` class which takes in a cell and returns its adjacent blocks, which as you noted, depends on whether a cell is on either a left/right border, up/down border, or one of each. Rather than update the weight in the `Grid`, I would have the `Grid` contain a `Node` class in each cell, where the `Node` has a cost attribute signifying the cost of the path till that point